# I have an excel sheet which have columns level 1, level 2, level 3, 4 and 5. How to read the excel in order to get the data in the xml as shown below?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Level 2 may have one or more properties for level 1. Similarly for other levels. It looks like a tree diagram of various levels. 
I want to convert the data into an xml in the order of levels.

```
<level1 name = Comprehensive view of customer and involved party>
   <level2 name = Profiles >
     <level3 name = Core Information ></level3>
     <level3 name = Interaction History> </level3>
     <level3 name = Holdings> </level3>
   </level2>
</level1>
```

Can anyone give me idea of converting the excel to xml?

Comment: See if this post http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076189/enterprise-java/book-excerpt--converting-xml-to-spreadsheet--and-vice-versa.html?page=2 will be of any help to you

Comment: This site gives the example of parsing excel having normal data. But, I need to parse a tree like excel in which each level has multiple levels in it.

Comment: observe the class public class ExcelToXML  and insert your customized scenario ( from what you said you don't need to change much at all)